# Check if a given polynomial is primitive

Tags: numerical-algorithms, polynomials, crc

I try to estimate error detection capabilities of arbitrary CRC polynomials. One important criteria is if a given polynomial is primitive. So I need an algorithm to check that. My goal is to write a C or C++ routine.

Unfortunately I only found analytical solutions for the problem on the web.

Is there some numerical algorithm for testing a given polynomial for primitivity?

Please consider that my mathematical knowledge wasted away during the last two decades. Any algorithm descriptions, pseudo code or code in a common programming language would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to check that a degree $n$ polynomial $P$ over $GF(2)$ is primitive, you first need to know the factorization of $2^n-1$ (you can look it up in [tables](https://oeis.org/A001265/a001265.txt), or use a CAS). Then, you test that $x^{2^n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{P(x)}$ (using repeated squaring to do this efficiently), and that for every prime factor $p$ of $2^n-1$, $x^{(2^n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{P(x)}$.

You can also just use a CAS (computer algebra software). For example, using the free software Sage you can do

```
F.<x> = GF(2)[]
(x^8+x^6+x^5+x+1).is_primitive()
```

For more on the relevant mathematics, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks).

Comment: Do you know if there is a simplified algorithm considering that CRC polynomials are pretty simple, having only terms with coefficients that are either 0 or 1?

Comment: @Silicomancer Polynomials over $GF(2)$ always have zero-one coefficients.

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me read more about that. Totally forgot the notations :(

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the description correctly. `x^(2^(n−1)) ≡ 1 (modP(x))` means I devide `x^(2^(n−1))` by `P(x)`, then I devide `x^0` by `P(x)` using polynomial division. Than I take both remainders and check if they are equal. Is this correct?

Comment: @Silicomancer That's right.

Comment: My CRC polynomials can be 64 bit wide. I.e. highest term `x^64` and `n=64`. `x^((2^n)−1)` would grow up to `x^((2^64)-1)` which is an insanly huge polynomial term. Trying to do polynomial division to such a term would probably take forever. I think I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Silicomancer What you're missing is the algorithmic technique of repeated squaring.

Comment: @Silicomancer The repeated squaring algorithm is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: I think I understand that repeated squaring method. At least for calculating concrete numbers (like `x^((2^64)-1)` with `x=42`) it seems pretty easy. However I was not able to wrap my mind around how to apply it to the above problem. I do not have a concrete x. I could probably convert `x^((2^n)-1)` to some nested exponential expression (being faster to calculate) for a given `n`. But in which way would that help me to do the desired polynomial division `x^((2^n)−1) / P(x)` ?

Comment: @Silicomancer You just repeatedly square $x$ modulo $P(x)$, and then multiply things out (modulo $P(x)$) until you get $x^{2^n-1} \pmod{P(x)}$. If you want to know more, you are welcome to ask another question.